# modifying code in the innermost loop to calculate percentages of gene overlaps between different gene lists

Tags: r, matrix, rstudio

I currently have some code that works to calculate the overlap between 8 different gene lists to see how many genes are common to two lists at a time. I would like to modify the code so that I can get the same result but in terms of percentages. Please find the code below:
The innermost loop needs to be altered according to the following:
1. Get max of g1 and g2
2. Divide overlap by the max
3. Calculate the %

I understand the steps I need to take but I struggle when it comes to modifying code as error messages tend to occur. If anyone could help that would be great!

```
filelist <- list(data.file1, data.file2, data.file3, data.file4, data.file5, data.file6, data.file7, data.file8)
all(sapply(filelist, file.exists))

# read files:
gene.lists <- lapply(filelist, function(f) {
  scan(file=f, what=character())
})


# set up empty matrix
x <- (length(gene.lists))^2
x
y <- rep(NA, x)
mx <- matrix(y, ncol=length(gene.lists))
mx
row.names(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
colnames(mx) <- sapply(filelist, basename) %>% stringr::str_remove('.txt$')
mx

mx.overlap.count <- mx

# seq_along(gene.lists) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
  g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
  for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
    a <- intersect(g1, g2)
    b <- length(a)
    mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
  }
}

mx.overlap.count
View(mx.overlap.count)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# looking at gene overlaps in terms of %

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# modify the code written above by adding the following to the innermost loop:
# get max of g1 and g2
# divide overlap by the max
# calculate the %
```

Below you will see the code for attempting to calculate the values as percentages -

```
# seq_along(gene.lists) # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
mx.overlap <- mx
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
  g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
  for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
    a <- intersect(g1, g2)
    b <- length(a)
    maxN = max(length(g1), length(g2))
    mx.overlap[j,i]= 100* b / maxN
    mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
  }
}

mx.overlap.count
View(mx.overlap.count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using something like:

```
for (i in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
    g1 <- gene.lists[[i]]
    for (j in seq_along(gene.lists)) {
        g2 <- gene.lists[[j]]
        a <- intersect(g1, g2)
        b <- length(a)
        maxN = max(length(g1),length(g2))
        mx.overlap[j,i] = 100 * b / maxN
        mx.overlap.count[j,i] <- b
    }
}
```

should work.

Comment: I added this code but i am getting the same results as before i.e. not percentages?

Comment: what do you have ? you should have a value between 0 and 1 in mx.overlap. This is not what you want ?

Comment: I am getting the number of overlaps between the different gene lists. For example, there are 175 genes common to BCGdown_D and BCGdown_V. However, i would like to generate a this is a % (using the longest of the two gene vectors when dividing) and then multiplying by 100

Comment: I edited my answer to include the two lines of code I suggest. You should have what you want in mx.overlap (that you should first create like mx.overlap.count)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - I've tried your edited code and I got the following error message: Error in mx.overlap[j, i] = 100 * b/maxN : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix Any ideas?

Comment: did you put a line to create mx.overlap before the loops (ie: mx.overlap <- mx)

Comment: Yes that resulted in no difference. I am still getting the same values as before. I will edit the question above to show you the steps I have taken based on your advice

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean by "getting the same values as before".  `mx.overlap.count` will indeed have the same values as before, but the percentages you are looking for should be in `mx.overlap`. What is in `mx.overlap` at the end ?

Comment: Thank you so much for being patient with me! I have just checked the code and realised I was looking at mx.overlap.count instead if mx.overlap. Sorry about that and thanks again for your help